# Calculating surface area of parametric surface when integral has square root

Tags: calculus, surfaces

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4sGB.png)

#### Approach:

The parametrisation of the surface is given. So I just have to doubly integrate the standard formula for surface area over the required region.

#### Problem:

(Please refer to below): My double integral involves a square root of a square.

$$\iint \sqrt{2(u-v)^2} \ dA $$

My tutor pointed out that we "must consider both cases", i.e.

$$= \iint \sqrt{2} (\color{red}{u-v}) \ dA$$

AND

$$= \iint \sqrt{2} (\color{red}{v-u}) \ dA$$

But I am stuck as to what to do next - what is the end result? What is the actual surface area?

Thank-you kindly for reading, and any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you just need to compute the intergral! 
Use the linearity property of integrals: $\iint\sqrt2(u-v)dA=\sqrt2(\iint (u-v)dA$. I'm just going to assume that $dA=dudv$ here. So $\sqrt2\iint (u-v)dA=\sqrt2\iint(u-v)dudv=\sqrt2\int (\frac{u^2}{2}-uv+C)dv$ and I leave the rest to you!
 Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer one over pie :)

Just a follow up question if you don't mind; what do I do with the fact that I now have _two_ integrals?   Do I just add the end results together?

Comment: What do you mean you have 2 integrals now? You should have just one

Comment: To evaluate the double integral, I had to split the domain into 2 parts - first part is when u > v and the other is when u < v - therefore I had two double integrals to evaluate to 2 (different) sets of limits.